# Do arithmatic inside database. Is this possible?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to this dynamically `Add(stage_1 + stage_2)` and get the total saved into the column called `total`. I am using phpMyAdmin. And the stage columns are of type `float`.

```
    Car    stage_1    stage_2      total
    1        30         50          80
    2        28         51          79
    3        31         51          82
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update cartable set total = stage_1 + stage_2
```

In fact, instead of storing the column total in the database, you could just create a view:

```
create view carview as 
       select Car, state_1, stage_2, stage_1 + stage_2 as total
       from cartable
```

Comment: The first piece of code works ok but everytime i update the database i have to enter the code to get updated values in the total column. Is there any way to do this automatically

Comment: does the second piece work? i think it should... you don't really want to store the total in your table, as that is redundant - it can be recalculated at any time!

Comment: (but if you really, really have to do this, look into triggers)